# Illegal assignment from void to LIST<>

Tags: sort

I am trying to sort a list of sObjects using compareTo method example.

Getting the error a mentioned in the tittle.

Code below:

> ```
> public inputnulls(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) { 
>     accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); // gets parent id (monitor)
>     mycon = controller; 
>     Selectedmeters = mycon.getSelected(); 
>     selectedmeters = selectedmeters.sort();
> }
> ```

I can post the whole class if this is not enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This line cause problem:

```
selectedmeters = selectedmeters.sort();
```

Sort is void method, please check:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm